# How do I use brew installed Python as the default Python?

Tags: python, homebrew

I try to switch to Homebrew (after using fink and macport) on Mac OS X 10.6.2. I have installed python 2.7 with

```
brew install python
```

The problem is that, contrary to Macport, it seems that there is no python_select utility, and my default mac python is always default

```
which python
```

give me

```
/usr/bin/python
```

and `/usr/bin/python` is not a symlink

How can I do to make python brew flavour to be my default python ?

Comment: Homebew no longer shadows the system installation of python. You can do: `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"` source: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/what-happened-to-the-standard-python-package/935

Comment: I tried all the mentioned answers, /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin in my $PATH. I tried brew link and unlink, brew doctor didn't report the /usr/bin being before /usr/local/bin an issue. Still when I do which python, I get /usr/bin/python and not the one installed with brew.

Comment: try... which python2

Comment: It's not recommended anymore to use Homebrew Python for local projects. See [Homebrew Python Is Not For You](https://justinmayer.com/posts/homebrew-python-is-not-for-you/)

Comment: if you're using python3, try 'which python3' . If that works then 'python3 --version' and 'pip3 --version' should work

Comment: I followed fn control option's advice and only then everything worked. asdf is the way to go!!!

Answer (score 156):

As suggested by the homebrew installer itself, be sure to add this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: This is the correct method on High Sierra. Vote up!

Comment: MacOS defaults to the zsh terminal, so chances are it is the `.zshrc` file and not the `.bashrc` file that needs to change.

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me except this! running macOS Catalina here. Thanks!

Comment: Seemed to work for big sur. Note: needed this for identifying where python was for OBS, since OBS seemed to require python 3.7. Brew installed 3.9.

Comment: Getting python scripts in OBS actually turned out to be a thing. Leaving this here, in case someone happens upon the trail: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/mac-python-support-in-obs-26.130960/post-530313 .

Comment: Works on macOS Monterey

Comment: For MacOS on Apple Silicon/ARM, this will rather be: export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH" (Homebrew's default location is different)

Comment: On my machine (MacOS Ventura, Apple M1) it needed to be: export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3/libexec/bin:$PATH" .

Comment: This is just adding to all the OP comments here.

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin:$PATH" seemed to work for me. 

NOTE: Add the version number while adding the export to your profile file either .zprofile or .bashrc or .zshrc

Answer (score 137):

As you are using Homebrew the following command gives a better picture:

```
brew doctor
```

Output:

> ==> /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those provided by
>   Homebrew. This is an issue if you eg. brew installed Python.
>
> Consider editing your .bash_profile to put:   /usr/local/bin ahead of
>   /usr/bin in your $PATH.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have /user/local/bin TWICE in your path. For some reason in my PATH it appeared both before and after /usr/bin and it was driving me crazy.

Comment: many programs use /usr/bin/python in the header making this not a viable solution.

Comment: for brew in High Sierra only `python2` is in /usr/local/bin, for just `python`; set  `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"` in `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 111):

See: [How to symlink python in Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354207/how-to-symlink-python-in-homebrew)

```
$ brew link --overwrite python
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3... 28 symlinks created
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: why doesn't this happen when I brew install python?

Comment: @BenWest because python3, now you get python2 rather then python.

Comment: @minseong that is likely due to System Integrity protection.

Comment: I don't have it enabled.

Comment: In my case, I needed to restart the terminal after running this command (as noted by [Martijn Courteaux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39828525/3427178))

Comment: this links python@2 for me

Comment: um that doesn't work... `brew link --overwrite python` says `Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5` but then `which python` still points to `/usr/bin/python` and `python --version` is still `python 2.7.16`.

Answer (score 106):

For Apple Silicon machines, the path are slightly different. After running `brew install python`, you must ensure your `~/.zshrc` uses the correct Homebrew paths:

```
# Homebrew
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

# Homebrew: Python
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Results:

```
% which python
/opt/homebrew/opt/python/libexec/bin/python

% python --version
Python 3.9.9

% which pip
/opt/homebrew/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip

% pip -V
pip 21.3.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

**UPDATE 2023**

Brew python changed it's location again and had to update my `~/.zshrc` to:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/python@3/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

There isn't a `.../opt/python/...` anymore which is annoying because now I have to specify v3 explicitly, but at least better than having to specify the minor version like in the comments.

Comment: it looks like python version should be specified: `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/libexec/bin/`

Comment: Thank you — that worked for me on my M1 MacBook (and nothing else here did!)

Comment: This worked when nothing else did on Mac M1. Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct answer for ARM Macs, thanks a lot!

Comment: Note `.../opt/python/...` is back and there's no need to use `python@3` anymore

Comment: As of Feb18 2024, I had to add the `python@3.12`. This took way longer to figure out than it shoudl have...

Answer (score 68):

Quick fix:

1. Open `/etc/paths`
2. Change the order of the lines (highest priority on top)

In my case `/etc/paths` looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

If you want to know more about paths in OSX I found this article quite useful:

http://muttsnutts.github.com/blog/2011/09/12/manage-path-on-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: Thank you, all above answers did solve my problem, but your did! Thank you so much!

Comment: the problem with this is that it changes it for all users :/, IMO it's better to change something more specific.

Comment: @RandallHunt like what and how?

Answer (score 49):

I did "brew install python" for OSX High Sierra. The `$PATH` had `/usr/local/bin` before any other path but still `which python` was pointing to the system's python.

When I looked deeper I found that there is no python executable at `/usr/local/bin`. The executable is named `python2`. To fix this problem create a symbolic link `python` pointing to `python2`:

`/usr/local/bin $: ln -s python2 python`

Comment: Confirmed this fixes the issue on High Sierra

Comment: You are my hero. Can't believe I didn't realize this solution!

Comment: Also need restarting the terminal for apply

Comment: $ cd /usr/local/bin
    $ ln -s python3 python

Comment: and I suppose also sym-link pip to pip3 (or pip2)?

Comment: fixed my problem with python3.9 on Big sur

Answer (score 29):

`python` formula now uses `python3`(v3.6.5 for now), brew will link the **directory**:

```
/usr/local/opt/python -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5
```

it will also link the **binary**:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/python3
```

If you still need to use `python2.x`, use:

```
brew install python@2
```

To use homebrew's `python`, just put its directory in PATH, for bash:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

for fish:

```
set -x PATH /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin $PATH
```

Note:

1. doing this will shadow the system default version of `python`
2. homebrew used to link python to `/usr/local/share/python` in older versions.

Comment: This was the trick for me. By default, brew installs `python3` in your path - _not_ an exec called `python`.. Specifically referencing `/usr/local/opt/python/libeexec/bin` ahead of other directories in my path sorted things out.

Answer (score 24):

Homebrew does NOT replace stuff in "/usr/bin". You'll just want to put "/usr/local/bin" ahead of "/usr/bin" in your path, then "which python" will give you "/usr/local/bin/python".

Replacing /usr/bin/python (or /usr/bin/ruby) is highly unrecommended.

Comment: But it doesn't!

Answer (score 16):

Modify your $PATH, Add this in your bashrc or bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH
```

more click here:
[Issue #89791](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8791)

Comment: My editor "PyCharm" was using ~/.bashrc and I was unable to get brew's python working until this little gem. Thanks @Aben

Answer (score 15):

I did `brew install python`, my `$PATH` was good, but still, `which python` gave me the system installed one. Restarting the terminal fixed it.

Comment: This is all I needed to do. I'm not sure when to do this, though. It sounds like just execute `brew install python` and then, restart terminal, and nothing else? No need to `brew unlink` & `brew link`?

Comment: Right after installed python using brew, "which python" give me the correct local python path, but "python" command indicated that it was the system installed one invoking. Restart terminal fixed it.

Comment: restart terminal is not necessary, try `hash -r`

Comment: JFC, I was losing my mind until I read this. I already did `brew unlink & brew link` several times. Only needed to restart the terminal

Answer (score 10):

You need to edit your PATH environmental variable to make sure wherever the homebrew python is located is searched before /usr/bin. You could also set things up in your shell config to have a variable like PYTHON be set to your desired version of python and call `$PYTHON` rather than `python` from the command line.

Also, as another poster stated (and especially on mac) DO NOT mess with the python in /usr/bin to point it to another python install. You're just asking for trouble if you do.

Answer (score 7):

`python` now points to `python3`, if you need `python 2` then do:
`brew install python@2` and then in your .zshrc or .bashrc file
`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@2/libexec/bin:$PATH"`
Now, `pyhon --version` = Python 2.7.14 and `python3 --version` = Python 3.6.4. 
That's the behavior I'm used to seeing in my terminal.

Answer (score 6):

I believe there are means to make homebrew python default, but in my opinion the proper way to solve a problem is not to mess with system python paths: it is better to create a virtualenv in which homebrew python would be default (by using virtualenv --python option). Using tools like `python_select` is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Add the `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` explicitly to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

After that, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Use pyenv instead to install and switch between versions of Python. I've been using rbenv for years which does the same thing, but for Ruby. Before that it was hell managing versions.

Consult [pyenv's github page](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for installation instructions. Basically it goes like this:
- Install pyenv using homebrew. `brew install pyenv`
- Add a function to the end of your shell startup script so pyenv can do it's magic. `echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile`

- Use pyenv to install however many different versions of Python you need. `pyenv install 3.7.7`.
- Set the default (global) version to a modern version you just installed. `pyenv global 3.7.7`.
- If you work on a project that needs to use a different version of python, look into `pyevn local`. This creates a file in your project's folder that specifies the python version. Pyenv will look override the global python version with the version in that file.

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
brew install python
brew link python
```

After doing that, add this to your bashrc or bash_profile:

```
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python2'
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It sounds like you ran into the same problem I did. All the links that brew creates, even with the `link` commands in answers here, in `/usr/local/bin` are for `python2` instead of `python`. Using an alias to work around this seems like a bad idea, but I haven't found anything better yet.

Comment: Rather than alias, I just copied it `cp /usr/local/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python` and it seemed to work well. Is this an even uglier work-around?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
which python3
```

Try typing `python3` instead of just `python`

Comment: The issue emerges when some of the scripts are trying to use `python` command, so you can't simply replace `python` with `python3` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit /etc/paths. Here is mine:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Then add a symlink for the python version. In my case

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ln -s python3 python
```

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

If you are fish shell

```sh
echo 'set -g fish_user_paths "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin" $fish_user_paths' >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Answer (score 1):

Greeting folks! I have the need to use python 3.10 version to harness its new features. My solved solution at 2022-07-03 is as follows. Have fun coding python!

```
» rm '/usr/local/bin/pip3.10'
» brew link python@3.10
» echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
» python3
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun 23 2022, 17:15:25) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, if you installed Python3 via Homebrew with `brew install python3`, then you need to run the following command via terminal:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

This is for the latest Python version 3.11. Make sure to edit the command to correspond with your Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Since High Sierra, you need to use:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

This is because `/usr/local` can no longer be chowned

Answer (score 0):

```
brew link python
```

And you must create/add an alias for python and put it in your .zprofile (Located in Users/username folder, if you press Shift+command+.

This must point to your homebrew python installation location.

```
alias python ='opt/homebrew/bin/python3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just in case anyone needed something I needed i.e. just to play around with Python a bit, you may as well call it from terminal with

```
python3 my_python_file.py
```

considering python 3.x is installed, of course, in my case using brew.