# fontforge python bindings with macports

Tags: python, macports, fontforge

I am on Mac OS X and I would like to use a python script like [this one](http://crimsontext.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/crimsontext/trunk/tools/generate.py?revision=96&view=markup&pathrev=96) to manipulate an OTF with fontforge. The problem is, how do I access fontforge? Do I need a special build for that?

This is what I get when I run the file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import fontforge
ImportError: No module named fontforge
```

(line 6 is `import fontforge`)

Comment: You might want to follow this ticket: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31852

Comment: @topskip I wonder if you remember if or how you finally fixed this? Thanks.

Comment: @FromWhereToWhere I don't remember, I think I gave up on that.

Comment: @topskip thanks for the response. I actually just switched to Ubuntu and installed it as [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ufo2otf/0.2.2): $ sudo apt-get install fontforge python-fontforge  <-- Then it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

first uninstall what you currently have installed:

```
port uninstall fontforge
```

then install the python variant:

```
port install fontforge +python27
```

there's also a python26 variant. to see all variants `port variants fontforge`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Looks like you need to install python with brew and point to brew's python (as mentioned in @davelab6 comment). So first install python and fontforge

```
brew install python    
brew install fontforge
```

Then as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48101303/4706073), add below to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score -2):

You can get the FontForge development version's python module with HomeBrew:

```
$ brew install python
$ brew install fontforge --HEAD
```