# How to make Homebrew Python the main one I use?

Tags: python, homebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python homebrew by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157678/python-homebrew-by-default)

When I type the following in the terminal I get this: I need it to point to the Homebrew Python.

```
whereis python = /usr/bin/python
which python  = /Library/Framewroks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Comment: Which one is the "Homebrew" python?  It looks like you just need to mess with the order of your `PATH` to move either `/usr/bin/` before `/Library/Framewroks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` or vice-versa (assuming one's not a symlink to the other)

Comment: When I do "brew link python" it says "Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3 I can't get it figured out.