# Why is Ninja-ide unable to see the installed version of sip?

Tags: python, macos, ide

am trying to install and run Ninja-ide.  I have followed the instructions in the documentation [here](http://ninja-ide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)

I move to the Ninja-ide folder and run the suggested command:

```
$ python ninja-ide.py
```

and get the following:

```
XXXX-XXXX-MacBook-Pro:ninja-ide twmeggs$ python ninja-ide.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ninja-ide.py", line 26, in <module>
    import ninja_ide
  File "/Users/XXXX/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
import sip
ImportError: No module named sip
```

so I try to re-install sip with:

```
XXXX-XXXX-MacBook-Pro:ninja-ide $ brew install sip
```

only to be told that it's already installed:

```
Error: sip-4.13.3 already installed
```

Now, I will hold my hands up here and say that I'm only just getting used to using a shell to execute commands and only just getting used to the files/directory/folder layouts within a Mac, so it's completely possible that I've messed up something simple here.

If someone could offer some help, or even a nudge in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the thought seumas - I didn't have to do that in the end.

Turns out that although I'd downloaded and unzipped sip I hadn't installed it correctly.  I needed to run:

```
$ python configure.py
$ make
$ make install
```

from the sip folder

Once I'd done that I had to repeat the same for the PyQt package.  Having done that I could then launch Ninja-ide from the shell with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could have two different versions of python, try running:

```
brew doctor
```

It will tell you what duplicates exist, if you installed python via brew try editing your path to place usr/local/bin before usr/bin as described here

[python homebrew by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157678/python-homebrew-by-default)