# python feedparser ImportError: No module named feedparser

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, homebrew, feedparser

I receive an error when I attempt to include the feedparser library into the interactive Python environment:

```
>>>> import feedparser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named feedparser
```

This also happens with BeautifulSoup and pydelicious.  Why am I getting this error?

Using OS X 10.8.3, which include the following files in the /usr/bin directory:

```
$ ll python*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  58896 Mar 17 20:55 python
-rwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel    925 Nov 16 10:30 python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Nov 16 10:30 python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Nov 16 10:30 python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Nov 16 10:30 python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Nov 16 10:30 python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Nov 16 10:30 python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Nov 16 10:30 python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  58896 Mar 17 20:55 pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Nov 16 10:30 pythonw2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Nov 16 10:30 pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Nov 16 10:30 pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

Python's location:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Python's version:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.2
```

It was probably unnecessary, but I installed Python with Homebrew:

```
$ brew install python
```

Which installed these files:

```
$ brew list python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/smtpd2.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/smtpd2.7.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/smtpd.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/pythonw2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/pythonw2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/pythonw
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/python2-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/python2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/python-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/pydoc2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/pydoc2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/pydoc
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/pip-2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/idle2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/idle2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/idle
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/easy_install-2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/easy_install
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/2to3-2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/2to3-2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/2to3
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Build Applet.app/Contents/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/ (4858 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/IDLE.app/Contents/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Python Launcher.app/Contents/ (17 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/share/man/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/share/python/ (317 files)
```

Then I installed feedparser:

```
$ pip install feedparser
```

Which resulted in these files:

```
$ ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/f*
-rw-r--r--  1 foobar  admin  166583 Apr 24 20:16 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/feedparser.py
-rw-r--r--  1 foobar  admin  138040 Apr 24 20:16 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/feedparser.pyc
```

I was hoping to avoid these sorts of problems by using Homebrew (which has worked well with other libraries).  What am I missing?

Comment: The configuration problems that inevitably follow manual installations of packages (as opposed to a package manager).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python homebrew by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157678/python-homebrew-by-default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Python is at `/usr/bin/python`, then you are not using the Homebrew-built Python, but the OS X default one.  (Also note the version number discrepancies in your output.)  So any package that you install with `pip` will be installed into the Homebrew space, but will not be visible to the OS X-supplied Python installation.  (OS X does not supply `pip`, so that's quite like the Homebrew one.)

The fix for you is quite likely to update your path to have `/usr/local/bin` come before `/usr/bin`.