# Homebrew: Python version still 2.7.4 after homebrew install

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew

I've installed Python using homebrew. `which python` returns `/usr/local/bin/python` which should be the homebrew install, if I'm not mistaken. When I run `python`, I get

```
Python 2.7.4 (v2.7.4:026ee0057e2d, Apr  6 2013, 11:43:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

which tells me I'm still on version 2.7.4 rather than 2.7.5. If I then run `brew upgrade python`, I get `Error: python-2.7.5 already installed`.

Can anyone help me figure out what's happening here?

Comment: Can it be that 2.7.5 is indeed installed and the problem is that `/usr/local/bin/python` still links to the old version. Take a look inside `/etc/` to see if you can find your 2.7.5. Does your OS have something like `update-alternatives`?

Comment: Thanks, @Hyperboreus. I think I found the solution. See my updated question.

Comment: Glad to help. Post your update as an answer and accept, so future users facing the same problem can find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the answer in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157678/python-homebrew-by-default). I was able to use [@akauppi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645426/800492) to fix my problem. I'm guessing the symlink in /usr/bin/local/ was pointing to the system python or maybe just another older version I have on my system somewhere instead of the version installed by Homebrew. By running `brew link --overwrite python`, I was able to replace those old symlinks and I now show version 2.7.5 when I run `python`.