# How can I use Homebrew to install both Python 2 and 3 on Mac?

Tags: python, homebrew

I need to be able to switch back and forth between Python 2 and 3. How do I do that using Homebrew as I don't want to mess with path and get into trouble.
Right now I have 2.7 installed through Homebrew.

Comment: You might want to change the question to remove homebrew reference since it is not necessarily a requirement to accomplish your goal (see my answer below for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/49091638/2923369)

Answer (score 302, accepted):

I would use [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) You can install it:

```
$ brew install pyenv
```

To enable pyenv in your Bash shell, you need to run:

```
$ eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

To do this automatically for Bash upon startup, add that line to your `~/.bash_profile`. <sup>1</sup>

### Usage:

Once you have installed pyenv and activated it, you can install different versions of python and choose which one you can use. Example:

```
$ pyenv install 2.7.5
```

You can check the versions you have installed with:

```
$ pyenv versions
```

And you can switch between python versions with the command:

```
$ pyenv global 3.3.1
```

Also you can set a python version for the current directory with:

```
$ pyenv local 3.5.2
```

You can check by running `python --version`:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Homebrew used to instruct you to do this upon installation of pyenv, but [the message was removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/d82ef4e9a5105c9c5da086025c57f89929811763). For Zsh and other shells, the precise steps may be different.</sub>

Comment: This is the simplest solution. I currently use this for switching between Python 3 and 2.7.x

Comment: Thanks. so how do I switch back and forth? should I pyenv the version I want to use each time I wanna switch?

Comment: If I have already installed python 2.7 through *homebrew*, is there anything I should take care of using *pyenv*? Can I install another python 2.7 through *pyenv*?

Comment: Yep, you can install another python 2.7 through pyenv. It will install that python in $PYENV_ROOT/versions. The other python 2.7 installed through homebrew may appear as "system" when you execute "pyenv versions".

Comment: I have installed `python2` and `python3` with homebrew. After installing `pyenv` and setting a `pyenv global 3.4.2` python3 is still linked to the previous python3 and I only see one version for system

Comment: I had to add `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to my .profile/.zshrc to get pyenv working.

Comment: @ilciavo, you may have to add `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to your ~/.bash_profile

Comment: `brew install pyenv` recommends something that works like that, @Rohmer @Jojanzing

Comment: once use pyenv to install a version of python, is there way to have the system default to using that version?

Comment: If you use zsh, you should follow the [README on pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout).

Comment: Does this still work with a Homebrew from after 1 March 2018?

Comment: Note that you may have to uninstall `binutils` from Brew on an M1 Macbook in order for pyenv to install 2.7 successfully.  It was failing for me with `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`

Answer (score 77):

You can have both versions installed at the same time.

#### For Homebrew >=1.5.0:

Since 1st March 2018 the `python` formula will be upgraded to Python 3.x, while a new `python@2` formula will be added for Python 2.7, specifically.

See [changes announcement here](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/) or the [final doc about using Homebrew for Python here](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python).

#### For older Homebrew:

For Python 2.x:

```
brew install python
```

For Python 3.x:

```
brew install python3
```

Now, you will have both the versions installed in your machine. When you want to use version 2, use the `python` executable. When you want to use version 3, use the `python3` executable.

Comment: the question is about using both

Comment: thanks for the update! I followed a similar route but had problems with having to set ``PYTHONPATH``at each change... any idea? besides that, ``pyenv`` is great.

Comment: Also, note that having python2 and python3 side by side, that python points to python2 and python3 points to python3 as expected.  However, a big gotcha is that pip does not point to pip2 as you might expect.  It actually points to pip3 (as does pip3 obviously).  To use pip2, explicitly use pip2.  A bit inconsistent having the non number suffix for python point to 2 but the non number suffix for pip points to 3.

Comment: This messes up common executables like pip. python3 will overwrite python2 pip in this case and that will be the default "pip" command

Comment: My copy of OS X came with 2.7.10, but Homebrew installed 2.7.11. However, my machine still runs 2.7.10 by default. Is there a way to change the default to the copy Homebrew installed without pyenv or changing my path?

Comment: @nipponese - You have to change your PATH, that's how the shell works.  So make sure your `PATH` environment variable includes the Brew bin folder `/usr/local/bin` at the *front* of the path.  Put this in `~/.bash_profile` or similar then `source ~/.bashrc`.  Then type `hash -r` to re-hash your bash shell (due to path changing).  Now `type python` should show `/usr/local/bin/path` and `python --version` should show the brew-installed version.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7375583/992887) for more.

Comment: In response to @kissgyorgy's comment: I had that issue, the last comment on this issue resolved it for me https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/50607, running `python3 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip` then `python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip` put things back to having `pip` refer to Python 2's `pip`.

Comment: 2018 update: https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/
Now `python` will default to Python 3, and to have both versions, Python 2.x is available with `python@2`

Comment: python@2 was deleted from homebrew as of January 1, 2020.

Answer (score 12):

Currently Homebrew provides two different formulas for Python 2 and 3. `brew install python` installs python3, and `brew install python@2` installs python2. More details in Homebrew docs:

https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python

If you currently have 2.x installed via Homebrew, Homebrew will give you a message such as:

```
Error: python 2.7.14 is already installed
To upgrade to 3.6.5, run `brew upgrade python`
```

If you run:

```
brew upgrade python
```

you should be able to do:

```
python --version
```

and

```
python3 --version
```

To see what versions of Python 2.x and 3.x installed.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you probably can just enter "python3" to run your most current version of python3.x and "python" or "python2" to run the latest installed 2.x version.

Answer (score 6):

There are ways to use both , but the simplest solution today is to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). pyenv allows easy switching between versions.
Here is what I did to set up:

**STEP1:**

Remove all pythons from your mac

```
 brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force python
 sudo rm -rf ~/miniconda3/
 sudo rm -rf ~/.conda/
```

Remove the following from `~/.bash_profile`

> `export PATH="/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`

and also the following from `~/.bashrc`

> ```
> export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
> export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google:$PYTHONPATH
> alias python="/usr/bin/python"
> ```

**STEP2**:

Install pyenv and the python versions you need

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 2.7
pyenv install 3.7.0
```

**STEP3**:

add `pyenv init` to `bash_profile` or `bashrc`

```
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**STEP4**:

Check what got installed

```
pyenv versions
```

> - system (set by /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/version)
>
>   2.7
>
>   3.7.0

**STEP5:**

Choose a default

```
pyenv global 3.7.0
```

When a project needs older version, just go its root folder and run

```
pyenv local 2.7
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) !

> ### Ballad of asdf
>
> Once upon a time there was a programming language
> There were many versions of it
> So people wrote a version manager for it
> To switch between versions for projects
> Different, old, new.
>
> Then there came more programming languages
> So there came more version managers
> And many commands for them
>
> I installed a lot of them
> I learnt a lot of commands
>
> Then I said, just one more version manager
> Which I will write instead
>
> So, there came another version manager
> **asdf version manager** - https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf
>
> A version manager so extendable
> for which anyone can create a plugin
> To support their favourite language
> No more installing more version managers
> Or learning more commands

https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf
https://github.com/tuvistavie/asdf-python
https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-plugins

Comment: Seems to me that these are not competing tools but the same tool, implemented once (and sometimes more than once) per language. Kind of like why we need something like the LSP as well, IMHO. https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/overview

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had the same requirement - to move between Python versions - but I achieved all I needed with only Python3.6 by building from source instead of using `homebrew`.

`git clone https://git.<theThingYouWantToInstall>`

Depending on the repo, check if there is MAKE file already setup for this option.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to just go to https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/ and download the latest python. It installed along side current python in my system.

Answer (score -3):

Okay, I was struggling with my brew installation of Python3, because I didn't have pip3

```
sudo pip3 command not found
```

and so I did

```
brew uninstall --force --ignore-dependencies python3
```

and installed the regular Python 3.6.2 from official distribution and then I had pip3 and all components were ok.

Comment: OP is asking about installing both.