# Python Script not executing in Light Table shows error

Tags: python, lighttable

Help! i am getting this error again and again....on light table while i m trying to run python code

```
 File "C:\Python34\Lib\site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is a code with installation.

Comment: It looks as though you're trying to run Python 3 code under a Python 2 interpreter.

Comment: What's the value of your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20555517/270986

Comment: I was frustrated so i passed every possible path to all folders. Here what i have set the path....C:\Python34\Lib;C:\Python34\DLLs;C:\Python34\include;C:\Python34\libs;C:‌​\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\tcl;C:\Python34\Tools\pynche;C:\Python34\Tools\Scri‌​pts; Any suggestion would be appreciated.I have been using python 3 only so how it would use python 2 interpreter.

Comment: I don't know Light Table, but if it works like other Python-aware IDEs then there *should* be a place somewhere in its settings (or the settings for the Python plugin) where you tell it which Python interpreter you want to use.  Did you find anything like that?

Comment: One more thought: you might also look into the value of your `PATH` environment variable.  It's possible that Light Table is (implicitly or explicitly) using that to find the Python interpreter to use.

Comment: Thanks Mark but nothing seems to work. Which other tool will be good to use for python? Any suggestions.

Comment: Hmm.  Post to the [Light Table mailing lists](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/light-table-discussion), maybe?  As to other tools, there are many free and non-free Python IDEs out there; a Google search would probably turn up better advice than I could give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea about the Light Table part, but the error you show is the one that you'd get if you were to somehow try to execute a Python 3 `print` function call under Python 2 (where `print` is a statement with a quirky syntax rather than a function).  Lines 175-176 of `site.py` in the Python 3.4 distribution look like this (modulo leading indentation):

```
print("Error processing line {:d} of {}:\n".format(n+1, fullname),
      file=sys.stderr)
```

and sure enough, if you try to execute that in a Python 2 interpreter you'll get a `SyntaxError`, with the cursor pointing to that same `=` sign:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  3 2014, 06:13:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("Error processing line {:d} of {}:\n".format(n+1, fullname), file=sys.stderr)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("Error processing line {:d} of {}:\n".format(n+1, fullname), file=sys.stderr)
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'd suggest looking closely at the settings for the Light Table Python plugin to see if anything's awry.  You should also check the setting for your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  If it includes a reference to the `C:\Python34` directory and you're running Python 2, that could be the cause of the problem.  Here's an example of the exact same problem on OS X, caused by starting Python 2 with a `PYTHONPATH` that refers to Python 3's library directory:

```
noether:~ mdickinson$ export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/
noether:~ mdickinson$ python2.7
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```