# Interactive Console in PyCharm wont load correct python version

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm getting the following error when I start an interactive console in PyCharm

```
File "C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\Lib\site.py", line 176
file=sys.stderr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
Couldn't connect to console process.
```

I've set the interpreter in Configurations to 3.4 and can run by programs correctly, I just can't load an interactive console.

Comment: site.py is loaded on startup . . . did that file get modified?

Comment: No it hasn't been modified. I've read that getting the error above is usually a symptom of the wrong python configeration [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637178/python-script-not-executing-in-light-table-shows-error)

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Sounds like you should double check the settings at "Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console" and verify that that's not different than what you specified at "Project > Project Interpreter"

Comment: Success, if you make that an answer I'll give  you the credit. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm has a few places you can set the interpreter.

Double check the settings at `Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console` and verify that that's not different than what you specified at `Project > Project Interpreter`

Comment: Apparently that worked but another problem was caused. I think it has something to do with Anaconda. I ended up downgrading to pycharm4.5