# Python 2 Won't Install on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, windows-8.1

I have python 3 currently installed on my system, and I wanted to also install python 2 alongside it. During installation, this dialog pops up:
[image: Error dialog]

However, I have a `python.exe` in the install folder. Running it in the command prompt gives the error shown below.
[image: Error]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555517/using-multiple-versions-of-python

Comment: That just says how to run specific installed versions - it doesn't cover what to do if the installation itself fails.

Comment: Another [link](http://superuser.com/questions/770895/unable-to-install-python-on-windows-8) perhaps more relevant to the installation issue. Suggests to check the installation log.

Comment: I think what's happening is that windows is using python 3 files in the python 2 environment, which is throwing errors. The only solution I have found so far is virtualenv

Comment: Apparently trying to create a new virtualenv throws the same `file=sys.stderr)` error

Comment: Try something silly like, install python 2.x after that install 3.x, maybe windows its just confused about the path python is using

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been able to use that specific machine for a while, but I've been trying to uninstall all python 3.x files so I could try that. I'll let you know how it goes.