# Nuke Accessing Wrong Version of Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nuke, compositing

I am experiencing a very similar problem to this one:
[Using multiple versions of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555517/using-multiple-versions-of-python)

The context of my problem though I believe is different enough to warrant a separate question. I receive this error when trying to launch the non-commercial version of The Foundry's Nuke. The error manifests similarly to this:

http://community.thefoundry.co.uk/discussion/topic.aspx?f=197&t=113695

,except the error message returned before the command prompt immediately closes is that displayed in the first link. This leads me to believe that Nuke is trying to access the wrong version of Python (currently it is trying to access
Python 3.5).

Assuming my line of thinking is correct, how can I change the version of Python that Nuke is attempting to access? None of the advice in the Foundry forum link proved successful either, I should mention. And according to what I have read,the latest version of Python to be used by Nuke is 2.7. So to ask the question more specifically, how can I make Nuke access Python 2.7 as opposed to Python 3.5? Both are installed on my desktop, 64-bit Windows 10.

[The syntax error returned as the prompt closes and Nuke fails to launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0uyj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have removed PYTHONPATH from System variables and Nuke9.0v8 non-commercial now appears to function properly. As this has not caused any problems with other applications and programs that rely upon Python 2.7 or 3.x, I believe this solution was sufficient in solving the problem I initially proposed. Previously I had specified the location of Python 3 within the Path variable, and this I have NOT modified. I imagine that this solution should be applicable to any software that generates the error message linked in the question.