# Installing OpenCV 3 for Python 3 on a mac using Homebrew and pyenv

Tags: python, macos, opencv, python-3.x

I am running Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan). I want to:

- Maintain my system version of Python as the default
- Install Python 3.5 alongside it
- Install OpenCV 3 and the Python bindings

I installed `pyenv` and Python 3.5 by following this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18671336/1410871

I activated my Python 3 installation and installed OpenCV 3 with Python 3 support like this:

```
pyenv shell 3.5.0
brew install opencv3 --with-python3
```

But when I launch an IPython shell and import `cv2`, I get an error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-72fbbcfe2587> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2

ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

why?

Answer (score 12):

Answering my own question: I have to manually create a symlink to the shared object file and place it in the pyenv Python 3 site-packages directory:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so ~/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so
```

Now the line `import cv2` works as expected in Python.

Answer (score 2):

opencv3 is keg only and does not get linked when installing via Brew

Do the following:

```
$ brew link opencv3 --force
```

This is a more controlled approach than creating symbolic links by hand.

Then you'll be able to:

```
$ python3
import cv2
```

Cheers

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work for me. Importing cv2 still returns "ImportError: No module named 'cv2'"