# Remove all Python versions and clean install Python 3

Tags: python, macos, installation, uninstallation

I have installed on my MacBook Air (v10.10.5) a number of different Python Versions (2.7, 2.6 + 3). I have tried changing python PATH settings, however, it has become too awkward to maintain. Because of this, I wish to uninstall all versions (without damaging my OS) and then clean install Python 3. How can I do this?

Comment: I am guessing you installed from using python.org's pkg? In the future, you can try using brew and pyenv to manage your python versions (see [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671253/how-can-i-use-homebrew-to-install-both-python-2-and-3-on-mac))

Answer (score -1):

First of, you cannot (**and should not!**) uninstall a version of python that is shipped with macOS. They are shipped for a reason and might break your system as soon as you remove them (as a lot of essential processes might rely on them).

Python2.7 for instance has been shipped with macOS for a long time. However, you are also able to download and install the same version of python (e.g. 2.7) yourself, which usually means you end up with conflicting versions and controlling your PATH becomes a fulltime job.

You are always safe to remove those versions that you installed yourself (but only those!).

***How to do so*** depends greatly on how you installed them. If you've done so via downloaded packages of python.org look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11196943/4041795) for uninstall instructions. If you used another application like brew or macports you need to follow the guidelines of those programs which could be easily fetched via a Google search.

Good luck!