# pyenv zlib error on MacOS:

Tags: xcode, macos, zlib, pyenv

## My goal

I am trying to install Python 2.7.5 and 3.6.5 side-by-side on my MBP with with pyenv.

## `pyenv` Installation

Following [How can I use Homebrew to install both Python 2 and 3 on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671253/how-can-i-use-homebrew-to-install-both-python-2-and-3-on-mac) , I tried:

```
$ pyenv install 3.6.5
```

Which erred with:

```
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.5.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.5...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.13.4 using python-build 20160602)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/d0/t8d3jjp161g2dyrd4k67ypc80000gn/T/python-build.20180426091253.34709
Results logged to /var/folders/d0/t8d3jjp161g2dyrd4k67ypc80000gn/T/python-build.20180426091253.34709.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/d0/t8d3jjp161g2dyrd4k67ypc80000gn/T/python-build.20180426091253.34709/Python-3.6.5/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/private/var/folders/d0/t8d3jjp161g2dyrd4k67ypc80000gn/T/python-build.20180426091253.34709/Python-3.6.5/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/private/var/folders/d0/t8d3jjp161g2dyrd4k67ypc80000gn/T/python-build.20180426091253.34709/Python-3.6.5/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/private/var/folders/d0/t8d3jjp161g2dyrd4k67ypc80000gn/T/python-build.20180426091253.34709/Python-3.6.5/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

## What have I tried

- Installing zlib: `brew install zlib`

## My question

How can I install multiple Python environment with `pyenv` on MBP?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

On Mojave, after installing Xcode command line tools, had to run the following:

```sh
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Comment: Thank you @samsin. This fixed the issue for me, after spending hours on it. OP should have marked it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, that is really useful answer, most of other comments reflect problem for Mac OS before Mojave

Comment: Can I ask how on earth you figured out to do that @samsin?

Comment: For anyone else who has Mojave and may still be having issues, see this github issue - https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1219

Comment: 2020 El Capitan this answer no longer applies, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54955286/5847511 is the solution to use!

Answer (score 47):

```
brew install zlib
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
pyenv install 3.7.2
```

Samsin's answer didn't work for me. I didn't have a `Packages` dir

Comment: This is what I just had to do to get "pyenv install" working on Big Sur

Answer (score 18):

On MacOS 11.1 (Big Sur) I eventually needed:

```
brew install bzip2
export LDFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/lib -L brew --prefix bzip2/lib"
export CFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include -L brew --prefix bzip2/include"
pyenv install 3.9.0
```

I added the export commands in ./bash_profile so next time I can just use pyenv if I need to install more versions.

Keep an eye on : https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1643 which tracks this, hopefully this will be fixed in pyenv.

Comment: I think you need to use the output of the `brew --prefix bzip2` command:
`export LDFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/lib -L $(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib"`
`export CFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include -L $(brew --prefix bzip2)/include"`

Answer (score 8):

I tried all the solution here with no success.

This is what worked for me on MacOs 11.2.1 (Big Sur):

```sh
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0
brew install pyenv bzip2 zlib xz openssl@1.1

## 3.6.8
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.6.8 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)

## 3.6.12
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.6.12 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)

## 3.7.9
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install 3.7.9
```

The solution is taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aputs/1e898436c70c23ea739899a7942a720a).

Answer (score 3):

The pyenv wiki has a page specific for common build problems. There are some possible solutions mentioned for the [missing zlib error](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#build-failed-error-the-python-zlib-extension-was-not-compiled-missing-the-zlib).

I have the same ZipImportError but with the following command installation is successful:

```
CFLAGS="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" pyenv install 3.6.5
```

Comment: This does not work on MacOS 11.1 (Big Sur) for me with Xcode 12.3. Some workarounds for that can be found here : https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1643 .

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Python 3.8.6 with `tkinter`, I built on Vincent Gerris's answer and [this blog post](https://blog.ferstar.org/post/issue-35/), and found success with

```bash
brew install bzip2
export LDFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/lib -L brew --prefix bzip2/lib"
export CFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include -L brew --prefix bzip2/include"
export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6' --enable-framework"
pyenv install 3.8.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The [solution by @mathsyouth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69908018/2227743) worked for me but I had to add `arch -x86_64` before the commands.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32428982)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've opened XCode recently and granted permissions during that first-open process.  This solved it for me.  Got the idea from:

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2112#issuecomment-1265874025

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with all of these attempts. But found a workaround solution.

I still see

```
pyenv install 3.8.8

python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.8/Python-3.8.8.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.8...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.7.1 using python-build 1.2.23-19-g9ee109b6)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/mx/kwgrm0vx6vn1r5ptjpr75tjw0000gn/T/python-build.20231201205607.30499
Results logged to /var/folders/mx/kwgrm0vx6vn1r5ptjpr75tjw0000gn/T/python-build.20231201205607.30499.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

## Workaround - Manually download pkg file from source

Download manually a release from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/
I downloaded and ran python-3.8.9-macosx10.9.pkg

~/.zshrc

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

# setting up for pipenv 3.8
export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH"
export CXX=clang++
export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib -L$(brew --prefix sqlite3)/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix sqlite3)/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix readline)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix sqlite3)/lib/pkgconfig"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:$PATH"
alias python="python3"
export PATH="/Users/yourname/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

```
➜  which python
python: aliased to python3

➜  which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

➜  pipenv shell --python 3.8
zsh: command not found: pipenv
➜  python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"

OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
➜  python3 -m pip install --user pipenv

➜  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -m site --user-base

/Users/yourname/Library/Python/3.8

➜  pipenv shell --python 3.8
Creating a virtualenv for this project...

(ai_sandbox) ➜  ai_sandbox jupyter-lab
```

at this point we are in business, I can proceed with python running allowing me to do what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

> This is for **MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1** for those who have been trying to install python on M3 macbook and having issues
> OR
> got **Homebrew** accidently installed in **/usr/local** or any
> **other** path **than** the **default '/opt/homebrew'**

**Properly uninstalling Homebrew**

go to -> https://github.com/Homebrew/install

> This page shows two terminal commands to uninstall homebrew  One
> interactive another non interactive.
>
> If your Homebrew is installed at base prefix location /opt/homebrew
> first command should do it for you.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

> Otherwise run below command

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

> Due to some reason I had to execute both 1 & 2 uninstall commands to
> properly uninstall it as mine got installed in /usr/local
>
> Next: Download Package Installer for macOS

go to -> https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/tag/4.2.4
Download the pkg file

> Run it, if it warns you with a popup that Command line tools are
> missing. Run: xcode-select —install
>
> Open a terminal and run

```
xcode-select --install
```

xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools

> If you see the message above look for a popup try moving or minimizing
> your large windows, it could be overlooked - Will request your
> permission to install xcode-tools, grant the same.
>
> It will download lot of files in the background to install the same
> for 5-7 minutes on a fast internet connection, otherwise wait longer.
>
> Once it is installed the popup will say

```
**‘The software is installed’**
```

> Now re-run the Homebrew pkg file
>
> It will show you below message

```
This package will install to:
    ⁃   /opt/homebrew on Apple Silicon
    ⁃   /usr/local/bin/brew and /usr/local/Homebrew on Intel
```

So depending on your processor, homebrew shall be installed soon.

Once the installer finishes go back to terminal and run below two commands -

```
brew help
```

> Homebrew should be setup properly at this point.
>
> Try installing a latest version of python to ensure all is well!
> Below few versions installed for me. More about this on a related pages here -> https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues

```
nr@MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv install 3.11.0
nr@MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv install 3.10.13
```

...

```
Installed Python-3.11.0 to /Users/nr/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0
```

> Quoting fernando for his answer / link for homebrew formula patch on python 3.8.6 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71518318/573848

```
nr@MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv install --patch 3.8.6 <<(curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/113aa84/python/3.8.3.patch\?full_index\=1)
```

...

```
Installed Python-3.8.6 to /Users/nr/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6

nr@MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/nr/.pyenv/version)
  3.8.6
  3.11.0
  3.10.13
```

Note: the pyenv could still fail to install some versions. I listed the ones which succeeded.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me on macOS Big Sur (11.6.1):

```
brew update
brew install bzip2
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/bzip2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
pyenv install 3.8.6
```