# How can i install python 3.6.8 alongside 3.7.x using brew

Tags: python-3.x, version

I have Python 3.7 installed on my mac with brew. However i need Python 3.6.8 to be installed alongside. I don't know how to find the brew formula for 3.6.8 to install this version. Can somebody please help me with this? (I found some examples with formulas for 3.6.5, but could not find any with 3.6.8).

Please note: I am specifically looking for a solution using brew install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Homebrew to install both Python 2 and 3 on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671253/how-can-i-use-homebrew-to-install-both-python-2-and-3-on-mac)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @thomaztony! I understand you want to use homebrew to handle your `python` installation, but have you checked out the `anaconda` package manager? Specifically `miniconda` will give you the cleanest install, and then python version environments are made simple: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html