# Switching Python version installed by Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I have Python 3.8 and 3.9 installed via Homebrew:

```
~ brew list | grep python
python@3.8
python@3.9
```

I want to use Python 3.9 as my default one with `python3` command. I tried the following:

```
~ brew switch python 3.9
Error: python does not have a version "3.9" in the Cellar.
python's installed versions: 3.8.6
```

I tried to uninstall Python and reinstall it, but it's used by other packages:

```
~ brew uninstall python
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6
because it is required by glib and php, which are currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python
```

How can I use Python 3.9?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671253/how-can-i-use-homebrew-to-install-both-python-2-and-3-on-mac

Comment: @Tom Are you sure it applies here? Python 2 and Python 3 are separate packages.

Comment: For me Brew was only addressing `python3` and would not add a `python` link. I had to go in and cut up my `.bashrc` and `.profile` to edit my `$PATH` which was getting mangled by some inserts, presumably from some earlier installs, and then add a `python` symlink to the `python3` that I wanted, alongside the `python3` symlink in `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

Comment: brew is not using `switch` anymore. Maybe we can update question and answer?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

There is an Homebrew known issue related to [side by side install of Python 3.8 / 3.9](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/62911). To workaround, following commands should work for you:

```
brew unlink python@3.9
brew unlink python@3.8
brew link --force python@3.9
```

Re-opening your terminal or execute command `rehash` can be required to take account the change.

Comment: Once followed the steps you described, it's ok to use `brew uninstall python@3.8` as it will be not have anymore dependencies?

Comment: Works for me without `--force` and console re-openning, at least `python3 --version` shows linked python version.

Comment: Also here is example where I have some problems after unlink / link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634761/env-python3-9-no-such-file-or-directory/68729295#68729295

Comment: The third command resulted in this error message: `Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3 Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists. You may want to remove it:  rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3' To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:   brew link --overwrite python@3.9`
I did that, and it worked 

Comment: It does not work for modern days... please disregard (I wish there is a modern day downvote button!)

Answer (score 7):

Use `pyenv`. It's a software that lets you switch between any and all Python versions installed on your system. To install `pyenv`, use the following code in the command-line:

```
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
exec $SHELL
```

Then find the name of the python version you want to switch to with this:

```
pyenv versions
```

And select it with this:

```
pyenv global <version-name>
```

In your case, it's most likely named `3.9.0`.

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to install `pyenv` through Homebrew?

Comment: The script above does install through Homebrew *and* sets it up to launch `pyenv` on bootup. @RoboRobok

Comment: How come? There's `brew install pyenv` for that :D

Comment: Yes, but it also modifies the on-boot script, which `brew install` doesn't do. It just is less hassle. @RoboRobok

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  After installing with "brew install pyenv" running "pyenv versions" only lists "system" despite me having 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10 installed via Homebrew too.

Comment: I previously installed python with Homebrew and had to remove it via "brew uninstall python@3.9". After that I installed a previous version via "pyenv install 3.8.6" and "pyenv versions" returned the correct version under "/Users/${USER}/.pyenv/version".

Answer (score 5):

> Updated MacOs Monterrey

For who are facing this problem add the pyenv path to your `~/.zshrc` shell file.

```
export PATH="/Users/username/.pyenv/shims:${PATH}"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

Run in the terminal:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Check it out:

```
python3 --version
```

From the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/849).