# env: python3.9: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have some python code formatters as git pre-commit hook and I have changed my python version as

```
brew list | grep python
python@3.7
python@3.9

brew unlink python@3.7
brew unlink python@3.9
brew link python@3.7

python -V
Python 3.7.9
```

and know seems something get broken and on git commit I get `env: python3.9: No such file or directory`, so what is `env`? and how I can edit it to use `python@3.7`?

Comment: I'd sugges to check code for the pre-commit hooks as most of the Python scripts start with a shebang line like `#!/usr/bin/env python`. You might have something like `#!/usr/bin/env python3.9` there. You can try to change it to `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7` but I cannot assure you it will work without problems, as some features of Python 3.9 might be used by scripts.

Comment: Regarding the `env` it's a shell command that starts programs in a modified environment. You can check some info about it running command `man env` on Linux/Unix.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/env

Comment: (a guess) if you're using [pre-commit.com] run `pre-commit install` and it will fix your shebang to point at your new global python version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `.git/hooks/pre-commit` I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
```

and running `pre-commit install` fixed it to `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7`

Answer (score 0):

Even though @mrgloom answer pointed me in the right direction, it wasn't good enough to solve my situation.

This error just happened to me after I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04. It clearly looks like the installed Python version isn't Python 3.9 anymore. So I quickly checked that right now I have 3.10.

Simply editing the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` with Python3.10 wasn't enough.

What worked for me was reinstall pre-commit: https://pre-commit.com/#install

So, you can either run `pip install pre-commit` or `brew install pre-commit`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I deleted the old virtual environment and re-Creating it and worked:

```
$ deactivate
$ python3 -m venv env
$ source env/bin/activate
```

Hope this would solve your problem, thank you!