# pre-commit x VSCode: env: python3.9: No such file or directory

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I use `pre-commit` to run `black` `flake8` and `isort` on my code.

I ran `pre-commit install` and as expected it created `.git/hooks/pre-commit` which starts like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
# File generated by pre-commit: https://pre-commit.com
# ID: 138fd403232d2ddd5efb44317e38bf03
import os
import sys
...
```

The hook works fine in the terminal:

```sh
$ git commit -am "remove commented block"
isort....................................................................Passed
black....................................................................Passed
flake8...................................................................Passed
[main f30007d] remove commented block
 1 file changed, 4 deletions(-)
```

But running it from VSCode's Source Control Panel yields an error (command output):

```sh
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
env: python3.9: No such file or directory
```

Not sure where that comes from. In addition (not sure it matters though) I double checked: both the terminal's `python` and VSCode's selected Python interpreter point to the same `/Users/victor/.pyenv/shims/python`

Comment: Note: I'm aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634761/env-python3-9-no-such-file-or-directory but it's a different matter

Comment: It's not Git or Python; it has something to do with the path that your shell is using (based on pathname I guess macOS and hence either bash or zsh most likely, so `$PATH`). Wherever you have `python3.9` installed, your *interactive* shell is able to find it, but your *non-interactive shell run from VSCode* isn't. How to fix that depends partly on the shell and partly on VSCode.

Comment: I'm on a mac indeed, with zsh+oh-my-zsh.
Any idea on what I should investigate next?

Comment: I don't use zsh but it tends to follow the standard setup of other shells: .zshrc, .zsh_login, etc., I think. Programs generally inherit $PATH from earlier programs, so if your $PATH is set correctly in your login shell, it remain set correctly in all subsequent programs. This means that bash users should put PATH-setting in `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, csh users should put it in `.login`, and so on; find the zsh login file, whatever they call it...

Comment: run `which -a python3.9` outside of vs code, and then inside of vs code figure out why that directory isn't on your `PATH` (it's likely due to missing some bashrc / etc. file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be an issue with `pyenv` not being loaded by VSCode's source control panel when executing the `git` commands.

I tried moving some stuff (like `$(pyenv init -)`) into an earlier zsh configuration file like `.zshenv` but that did not help.

In the end, specifying the complete path fixed it

```py
#!/usr/bin/env /Users/victor/.pyenv/shims/python3.9
# File generated by pre-commit: https://pre-commit.com
# ID: 138fd403232d2ddd5efb44317e38bf03
import os
import sys
...
```