# How to switch python version back to 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

Can't figure it out. Have Macos (Monterey) and because I've forget to disable auto-update for brew install I've got python 3.10 as default version after typing python in console.
How I can revert this to python3.9?

```
brew list | grep python                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
python@3.10
python@3.8
python@3.9
```

I was trying un-link python@3.10 and link python@3.9, can't figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching Python version installed by Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362772/switching-python-version-installed-by-homebrew)

Comment: If you want to uninstall v3.10, this might be it: [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: @roberthayek I've tried it earlier no luck

Comment: @windstorm which part of this long post ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyenv to manage your python version.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

python formulae are not good for your case, like Alex said, [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) should be the way to go.