# PyQt4 module not found

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, homebrew

I am new to coding and trying to run a .py. I am using Koopatlas and Koopuzzle to create NSMBW Maps. I have installed PyQt4 (I checked `brew list`) and Python but when I run it it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Koopuzzle.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

They're both in .py format, and they both give the same results.
I've checked online sources but I've found nothing. Does someone know how to solve?
Thanks, Gunner

Comment: You probably have multiple python installations on the system.
To check which one you are running, in the python interpreter: `import sys,  sys.executable`.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157678/python-homebrew-by-default

Comment: Elad, it says import command not found