# Error Installing OpenCV with Python on OS X

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew

I have been trying to install Open CV 3 on my mac using this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) but I cannot get past step three.

So after I do

```
brew install python
```

I do

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And the at the bottom of the script I paste

```
# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

After that I reload the file like this

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Finally I check the python like this

```
which python
```

And it prints

```
/usr/bin/python
```

instead of

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

I have also tried edited the file in TextEdit but it has the same result.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a bad tutorial?

Thank You in Advance!

Edit:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

##
# Your previous /Users/UserName/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/UserName/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2016-07-26_at_12:50:19
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2016-07-26_at_12:50:19: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

pydoc3.5
python3
python3-32
python3-config
python3.5
python3.5-32
python3.5-config
python3.5m
python3.5m-config

Comment: MacPorts and HomeBrew: just be careful that they don't interfere. Also, why install Python with HomeBrew when you also have a Python 3.5 installed in `/Library/`'. Sounds like you have a multitude of Python installation on your system, which at some point will bite each other.

Comment: The tutorial said this "t’s bad form to use the system Python as your main interpreter. And this is especially true if you intend on using virtualenv  and virtualenvwrapper"

Comment: If using your system Python is fine, there seems to be no need to install a Homebrew Python. Virtualenvs tend to be overrated, and mostly useful for development purposes: packages (and Python version) can be separated without virtualenvs and without problems when done properly.

Comment: Do you know any tutorials that use OpenCV with the system python becuase the only ones that I can find use HomeBrew Python

Comment: Just follow the instructions as they are and ignore the steps in which they say how to install homebrew's python. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/
```

directory? (Version number might differ.)

Is there a

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

file?

If the Cellar directory is present, but the file isn't, then Homebrew decided to be careful and not put Python in `/usr/local/bin/` immediately.
You could manually do

```
brew link python
```

and see if there's now a

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

file.

---

In your case, it appears you have some files related to Python (they might be from a Python 3 installation, can't tell), such as `2to3`. You can safely overwrite them, since Python 2 also has this. 
Thus:

```
brew link --overwrite python
```

is fine.

Note:

Specific Python versions will always exist as `python2.7`, `python3.5` etc (including the full path as necessary). Thus, even overwriting the `python` executable is safe (provided it's not the system one in `/usr/bin`): you should then simply be explicit which python executable to use.

Also, when using a tool like `pip`, you can make sure you're using the correct version by running it e.g. as

```
/usr/local/bin/pythnon2.7 -m pip <...>
```

or whatever python executable you want to install things for.

Comment: I got this error while I was linking python. Would I want to ovwrite those files                                                          Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you have existing files, which may be from a previous Python installation. You can safely overwrite them (but feel free to use the `--dry-run` option first). See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so one brute force solution could be this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/9821036/128517

But maybe you could check the value of your $PATH after `source ~/.bash_profile`
typing

```
> echo $PATH
```

and see if `/usr/local/bin` is indeed at the beginning.

if it's not, you might need to check if there's another export before yours or maybe you need to edit `.profile` instead.

Comment: Everything you have said matches. Do you have anyother ideas?

Comment: Maybe restart? No kidding.

Comment: have you checked if there's indeed a python bin at /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: There are a couple of things with python in it. I updated my question with all of the items with python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119055/discussion-between-hector-and-loanb222).