# Python module already installed but getting import error

Tags: python, module, pip, youtube-dl

I have started getting this error for a few modules in python after I 'brew installed python' on my OS X El Capitan. I know that Mac comes with python 2.7 but due to some issues I had to install python explicitly using brew. Now I get this error.

```
~/Desktop ⌚ 10:57:29
$ python f.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f.py", line 1, in <module>
    import youtube_dl
ImportError: No module named youtube_dl

~/Desktop ⌚ 10:57:30
$ pip install youtube_dl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): youtube_dl in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: What is your Python path (`echo $PYTHONPATH`)?

Comment: I get lots of paths using this command

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it by changing the path somehow. This helped : http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/09/27/use-python-effectively-on-os-x

Answer (score 1):

This error may come from :

1. The python you run by default isn’t the same that you call by your script : To check this, Please check this command (`$ which python`)
   Is this what you put on the top of your script?
2. Brew doesn’t make symbol link, it’s common issue : Please take a look here([python homebrew by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157678/python-homebrew-by-default))

I highly recommend to you virtualenv (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) so you can mange different version of python without altering your OS installation.

Using (`pip install youtube_dl`) like this, install the package for the current version of python. To be sure, just type (`$ pip freeze`).

Hope this helps. Good luck :)